# PyCharm for Python gives error for self is not defined

Tags: python, pycharm

My code has the following

```
import mod_curves
import mod_dates
import datetime
import modcalinputs

curvesclass = mod_curves.curvecalcs()
datesclass = mod_dates.datecalcs()
calcInputs = modcalinputs.calcinputs()

 1. List item

class payment_calculations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__accrualdays = 0
        self.__accrualrate = 0
        self.__coupondates = {}
....
```

When I run the PyCharm over any of the variables including the self in the **init** declaration I see the following reported by PyCharm (NameError)name ´self´ is not defined. This error appears on every variable in my code that starts with self.__

This is blocking any debugging I can do.

However, when I execute my code the app functions as expected.

How can I get rid of that error message_

Comment: Are you sure that you set the  _right_ `Python`  interpreter for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me, using PyCharm 4.5.3. Apologies if this is too obvious of an answer:

When debugging, you can only view contents of variables if the debugger is currently in a place where those variables are in scope.
For example, here I have set a breakpoint in main, where `self` and `self.__x` are not in scope.
[image]

Here, I have set a breakpoint in the constructor, where `self` and `self.__x` ARE in scope.
[image]

An alternative, if you want to access it from main, is you just access with the instance instead of with self, like this:
[image]

Comment: I downloaded the Educational version of the PyCharm about a month ago.

Comment: The code was written in Python 3.4 and it is that version I am using as the interpreter.

Comment: Wh en I check files without self.__ variables everything is fine.

Comment: Additionally I have set a watch for self.__accrualdays - when it is in focus i.e. in the __init__ for initialisation I see the error as above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly amongst the following worked - but something has

- Did an auto code cleanup
- Closed down PyCharm and reopened all the files
- Methodically went through the entire project and made sure every line of code was very tight without any form of errors.

Now when I set a watch against self.__ and related variables I do not see the error. I think part of the problem was that I wrote the code originally in IDLE and then copied the code across to a PyCharm project. Thus I did not have the PyCharm error checking etc. That meant I had a lot of unnecessary errors etc.